# Exploring potential relationship between variables using linear regression when cause-effect is not established

Tags: regression, correlation, causality

I have temporal data on an environmental stressor `temperature` and a continuous variable `ecosystem health`. They are moderately yet significantly correlated (i.e. r=-0.5; P<0.05). I do not know whether and how the increase in `temperature` caused a decrease in `ecosystem health`.

There is no clear evidence for causality or the mechanisms in which increased `temperature` may decrease `ecosystem health`, but there is a general expectation that there could be.

Is exploring the data using linear regression justifiable/defendable based on this general expectation?

I assume that if the expectation of causality is wrong, the prediction of the relationship may be misleading.

I am interested to hear some opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Not an attempt at a complete answer, but just some general thoughts too long for a comment:

What you know from your result is that the two are significantly negatively correlated in general. Presumably ecosystem health can not influence temperature so that seems unlikely direction. Nevertheless, it is certainly possible that this result only holds because you have not included some other important causal variables. For instance, assume a world in which some variable X has a positive causal relationship on ecosystem health, and that this X is the only variable with causal impact on it (eco. health). Assume also that X and temperature are both caused by variable Y such that they are correlated but no direct cause between the two. If this was the case, you could get significant correlation between temperature and eco. health even though there is no causal relationship. edit: to stress, this is just one example, many different possibilities exist.

One approach is to build a hypothesis of how you expect different variables to cause ecosystem health, temperature etc (e.g. drawing a causal graph / DAG may help) and then include appropriate controlling variables in you regression (s) to tease out any causal effect.

edit:
"Is exploring the data using linear regression justifiable/defendable based on this general expectation?"

In summary, I think it's fine to explore correlations. To claim it's causal, you need justifications that there are no relevant omitted variables (is this theoretically justifiable?) etc to support your expectation.